# How to select child element in each element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, each, show, mouseenter

i'm beginer in jQuery.
im try in to creat a tooltip. i have something like flowing code:

```
<div class="view-port">
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="product"></a>
        <div class="tooltip">some description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="product"></a>
        <div class="tooltip">some description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="product"></a>
        <div class="tooltip">some description</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <a href="#" class="item-link"><img src="product"></a>
        <div class="tooltip">some description</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to show `.tooltip` div in each `.item` element when the mouse enter the each `.item` element. i wrote the flowing code to do that:

```
$('.view-port').on('mouseenter', '.item', function(e){             
   $(' .tooltip').show();
});
```

but when i move the mouse on each item, all the `.tooltip` shown.

how can i fix that..?!

TnX

Comment: `$('.tooltip')` is selecting all instances of `$('.tooltip')` thus you've got to select the ***relevant*** `$('.tooltip')` in question, this is traditionally selected by `$(this)` which scopes to the current item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try this ([`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) will search the element in the current element selected with `$(this)`):

```
$('.view-port').on('mouseenter', '.item', function(e){             
   $(this).find('.tooltip').show();
});
```

or this:

```
$('.view-port').on('mouseenter', '.item', function(e){             
   $('.tooltip', this).show()
});
```

Comment: $('.tooltip', this).show() works as well, a slightly abbreviated version

Comment: Yeah I thought about that too and edited because the other solution was already explained.

Answer (score 4):

You can use .find() or .children() relativly to $(this)

```
$('.view-port').on('mouseenter', '.item', function(e){             
    $(this).find('.tooltip').show();
});
```

or

```
$('.view-port').on('mouseenter', '.item', function(e){             
    $(this).children('.tooltip').show();
});
```

Where $(this) = $('.item') relativly to $('.view-port')

Answer (score 2):

`this` inside the event handler refers to the current `item` element on which mouse entered, so use `this` along with [.find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

```
$('.view-port').on('mouseenter', '.item', function(e){             
   $(this).find('.tooltip').show();
});
```